# React Native: Image is not being rendered

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, reactjs, react-native

Hello I am having difficulty rendering the image of the movie poster following the guide. I checked multiple times but still can't find out why the image won't show.

Here is the gist: https://gist.github.com/josephan/3b73f894ebe10244e2cd6b1315ac65d8

And guide: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sample-application-movies.html#content

Comment: Can you post what you have done??I have also followed same example. it is working fine here.

Comment: I just tried to example in the first link and it works. Post your code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading the image via a http connection which will not work on iOS. You have to load it via a https connection. Try using a https URI and check if its working.

See also this post [React-native loading image over https works while http does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38153335/react-native-loading-image-over-https-works-while-http-does-not-work/38153336#38153336) and this one [Can't show Image by URI in React Native iOS Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38136981/cant-show-image-by-uri-in-react-native-ios-simulator/38153207#38153207)