# Image Not Loading in React Tutorial

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Does anyone know why the image may not be loading? index.ios.js is below, rest of the code is simply generated from

`react-native init TestApp`

I am not sure if the opening and closing tags are wrong or what. The image appears to load when I put it into my browser. [image]

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
var MOCKED_MOVIES_DATA = [
  {title: 'Title', year: '2015', posters: {thumbnail: 'http://i.imgur.com/UePbdph.jpg'}},
];

import {
  AppRegistry,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class TestApp extends Component {
  render() {
    var movie = MOCKED_MOVIES_DATA[0];
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{movie.title}</Text>
        <Text>{movie.year}</Text>
        <Image source={{uri: movie.posters.thumbnail}}
          style={styles.thumbnail}
        />      
        </View>
    );
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  thumbnail: {
    width: 53,
    height: 81,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('TestApp', () => TestApp);
```

Comment: Looks right. Have you tried putting the URI string into the Image tag directly instead of pulling it from the object variable?

Comment: The image is shown without any problem, see results here at https://snack.expo.io/BkuFE0MI-

Answer (score 3):

Add to your **Info.plist**

```html
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to load the image from a http connection and not from a https connection as recommended by apple.

You can fix it by editing info.plist as answered by Kawatare267

You can see more details here

Hope this helps.

[Can't show Image by URI in React Native iOS Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38136981/cant-show-image-by-uri-in-react-native-ios-simulator/38153207)