# Accesssing Value of Nested array in React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

am trying to access nested json array and display value in ,i can display all other json data in rowData and textfields but i cant display the one that has nested array.

**this is my json**

```js
[
  {
    Address: "Njjzjjz",
    created_at: "2018-08-17 23:55:43",
    email: "Helen",
    gender: "Female",
    id: 24,
    name: "Helen",
    password: "$2y$10$.0fahBOp94ABqY6NTDf9S.9w880dsMRS.0azq4wAiB6evOxSxFAfC",
    phone: "9997",
    profile_pic: ["ec9bbcd6df212029715a34fe825e8616.jpeg", "1960.png"],
    remember_token: null,
    state_of_origin: "Akwa Ibom",
    state_of_resident: "Abia",
    updated_at: "2018-08-17 23:55:43"
  }
  // More Objects are here
 ]
```

I have issue with profilepic

and this is how i display it in rowdata

```
 <View style={styles.MainContainer}>

   <ListView

     dataSource={this.state.dataSource}

     renderSeparator= {this.ListViewItemSeparator}

     renderRow={(rowData) =>

    <View style={{flex:1}}>

    <Image source={{uri:'http://192.168.43.71/upload/images/'+rowData.profile_pic[0]  // this is my problem}}
   style={{width: 400, height: 400}} />
    {this.test()}

      <Text onPress={this.GetItem.bind(this, rowData.email)} style={styles.textViewContainer} >{rowData.email}</Text>
      <Text onPress={this.GetItem.bind(this, rowData.password)} style={styles.textViewContainer} >{rowData.profile_pic[0]}</Text>
       <Text onPress={this.GetItem.bind(this, rowData.email)} style={styles.textViewContainer} >{this.state.photos[0]}</Text>

    </View>
     }
   />
```

Comment: than you for editing the question am trying to edit it but am not yet familiar with SO features,anyways i need help with the question,thanks in advance

Comment: may I know, For which platform you are building the app Android or iOS.

Comment: react native,android

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the width and height for the image.

```js
 <Image 
  source={{uri: "http://192.168.43.71/upload/images/" + rowData.profile_pic[0]}} 
  style={{width:100, height:100}}
  resizeMode="cover"
/>
```

You can choose from from different resize mode option depend on your requirment.

For more details check here:
[support Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38114325/cant-show-image-in-react-native)
[official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#resizemode)

Comment: yes the url is correct, and i can display other json data,the problem is i cant access the data in profile_pic[], it displays as arrays and when i use rowData.profile_pic[0] i get "[" on the console and if i use rowData.profile_pic[1] i get " " " on the console, if i use rowData.profile_pic[2] i get "e" on the console

Comment: I think in your json object the profile_pic is string not an Array. so when you try to print the profile_pic[0] it is retuning first character of string.

Comment: Declare your profilePic like this    profile_pic: ["ec9bbcd6df212029715a34fe825e8616.jpeg", "1960.png"],.  Not as you have copied first time in question