# Can't display Image for react-native app in android emulator

Tags: android, image, react-native

I am building a react-native app for android. I am trying to include image in my app. Whatever I do I cannot get the images to be displayed in my app. I have read this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38114325/cant-show-image-in-react-native) and tried with https images and added height and width to my image.
This is the render method of the component with the image Im trying to display. Right now the source points dynamically to my s3 bucket.

```
render() {
    const { textWrapperStyle, svgStyle, containerStyle, textStyle } = styles
    console.log("FILE URL", this.props.file.url)
    return (
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Modal
          animationType={'slide'}
          transparent={false}
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            alert('Modal has been closed.');
          }}>
          <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
            <View>
                <Image
                  style={{width: 200, height: 200}}
                  source={{uri: "https://obeya-dgeismar-site-assets"+this.props.file.url }}
                />

              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
                }}>
                <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
          </View>
        </Modal>
        <TouchableOpacity style={[containerStyle, this.props.customStyle]} onPress={() => {this.setModalVisible(true);}}>
          <View style={textWrapperStyle}>
            <Text>
              {this.props.file.title}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.confirmDelete(this.props.file.id, this.props.eventId)}>
          <Close style={styles.svgStyle} fill='red'/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Here's a [link](https://github.com/davidgeismar/timeo-mobile) to the whole project. I currently run it in android studio on a NExus 5x API 29 x86

Comment: If I type the address you are looking at in the Internet address bar, do you display the image correctly?

Comment: @hongdevelop yes it does

Comment: try passing prop  resizeMode="contain" in Image

Comment: and can you also show what result are you getting by consoling this line

console.warn(`https://obeya-dgeismar-site-assets${this.props.file.url}`)

Comment: Had a issue these days about CMYK type images. Try checking your error doing: `onError={({ nativeEvent: {error} }) => console.log(error)}` and see if it logs something

Comment: did you find the answer? Please do share