# Image not displayed in ReactNative in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<Image
   style={{}}
   source={{
       uri: 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png'
   }}
/>
```

Nothing is displayed on the screen

Comment: For network and data images, you will need to manually specify the dimensions of your image https://reactnative.dev/docs/image

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't show Image in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38114325/cant-show-image-in-react-native)

Answer (score 0):

Add styling to it like

```
<Image
  style={{
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    resizeMode: "center"
  }}
  source={{
    uri:
      "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png"
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the width and height for Image tag in the style.